# Like a specific photo in Facebook album outside of facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am totally new to this. What I want to do is to add a like button on an external website, which will then like a photo in one of the album in a page. I followed the instructions but still get "error" or page inaccessible whenever the like button is clicked.

The test page is at http://www.jeremyhoo.comlu.com/rosken/ try clicking the like button to see what I mean. Any idea how do I correct this?

Thanks Heaps!

Comment: [Facebook Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jeremyhoo.comlu.com%2Frosken%2F) is very useful for debugging these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `og:url` to `http://www.jeremyhoo.comlu.com/rosken/`